# package OSGI project as a single jar?

Tags: java, jar, osgi, package

I have a large OSGI package that I want to package and release as a single jar file.  I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is for packaging multiple jars into a single large jar.

So far the best option I've seen appears to be one-jar project.  However, the framework we are using pulls in jar files from a 'plugins' directory and one-jar appears to want/require all jar files to be stored only in the lib directory.  There may be an easy way around this, I haven't looked fully into the architecture enough to know as I'm still trying to decide what approach is best.

any suggestions for other approaches to package the multiple OSGI bundles into one jar and/or how I would go about making it work in one-jar is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to package the entire application, including OSGi runtime, as a single executable jar file; or, are do you want to somehow merge your bundles into a single bundle to simplify deployment into an OSGi runtime; or, or you trying to embed (non-OSGi bundles) into a single OSGi bundle?

Comment: I'm looking to to package everything into a single jar.  They should be able to run the program just by typing java -jar application.jar. for ease of use without installing a separate OSGI application.  The framework were using already loads the OSGI bundles from a plugin folder without using an external OSGI tool; so this is really as simple as managing a jar file that can have other jar files in it's plugins folder.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be to run your bundles using PojoSR instead of running them in an OSGi framework. PojoSR in a nutshell implements the service layer of OSGi without the module layer. One of the side effects of that is that you can easily package your application as an executable JAR file. When you run that JAR it also does not need to create a bundle cache on disk.

For more information on PojoSR, go to:

- http://code.google.com/p/pojosr/
- http://luminis-technologies.com/?p=358
- http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/pojosr

Answer (score 0):

Using the Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin, I believe the  option might accomplish what you are looking for.  http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

Comment: thank you for the link.  But I forgot to say were using ant for all our builds.  I'll look at the bundle you mentioned but I suspect since were not using Apache or maven at this time it won't be usable.

Comment: The plugin calls the BND tool.  You might be able to make a call-out to it using ANT.  I wouldn't be able to assist on how to do that though.

Comment: actually there is an ant goal for the plugin which I think is designed to allow the plugin to create an ant build.xml file.  I'll try working with it and see what happens.

Comment: Why do it in such a round-about way when you can use BND directly as an Ant task? See [aQute | BND: Ant Task](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Ant) However, I'm not sure BND can accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Sling's maven-launchpad-plugin generates a runnable jar (and optionally a war file and a Karaf descriptor) from a list of bundles, see http://sling.apache.org/site/maven-launchpad-plugin.html

The Sling installer can be used to load additional bundles from the filesystem or other sources, see http://sling.apache.org/site/jcr-installer-jcrjcrinstall-and-osgiinstaller.html